# Градиент в canvas

Tags: canvas, javascript, css

подскажите пожалуйста почему [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/tPdsH/) не действует градиент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в строке:

```
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,170,0);
```

создается градиент от 0 пикселя по 170, а прямоугольник рисуется от 520 (шириной 150) по 520+150 = 670

```
ctx.fillRect(520,420,150,100);
```

В `createLinearGradient()` нужно передавать координаты 2 точек (относительно 0, то есть, левого-верхнего угла холста). Переход будет идти от первой точки ко второй. В данном случае это должны быть точки `(520,0)` и `(670,0)`. [Вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/tPdsH/1/):

```
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(520, 0, 520+150, 0);
gradient.addColorStop(0.0, 'rgba(255, 12, 0, 1)');
gradient.addColorStop(1.0, 'rgba(0, 255, 54, 0.2)');
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;   
ctx.fillRect(520, 420, 150, 100);
```

А в твоем примере к 520-му пикселю цвет уже перешел в `rgba(0, 255, 54, 0.2)`